# Custom mining rewards

Tags: mining, ether, private-blockchain, gas, reward

Is it possible to give custom mining rewards or provide custom transaction fees for mining in a private chain? I am looking to create a contract which will reward the miners with data instead of / in addition to ether as an incentive to keep the network running

Comment: What kind of data are you talking about?

Comment: I am trying to understand a particular use-case of blockchain in healthcare, by [MedRec](https://www.healthit.gov/sites/default/files/5-56-onc_blockchainchallenge_mitwhitepaper.pdf) where they essentially store patient related data in traditional dbs and store pointers to them in a private blockchain. The chain in that case is run by doctors and researchers who would mine to get the patient treatment data, offered as transaction fees, as a reward for mining. Is it possible to have such reward structure?

Comment: Would it not be simpler to let the doctors mine "as usual" and have them exchange the crypto-currency for that data?

Comment: My bad; I guess that actually makes sense! Having control over the transaction reward type would eliminate the step of exchanging the ether, though (which can still be automated in the contract). If you can add your comment as an answer, I will accept it.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would it not be simpler to let the doctors mine "as usual" and have them exchange the crypto-currency for that data?